# How to generate seven-figure integer ranges with seq?

Tags: macos, seq

I am baffled by `seq`:

```
seq 218000 218010
```

will generate integers from 218000 to 220000 as expected:

```
218000
218001
218002
218003
218004
218005
218006
218007
218008
218009
218010
```

whereas:

```
seq 2180000 2180010
```

will output

```
2.18e+06
2.18e+06
2.18e+06
2.18e+06
2.18e+06
2.18000e+06
2.18001e+06
2.18001e+06
2.18001e+06
2.18001e+06
2.18001e+06
```

How can I use `seq` to output seven-figure integers?

Comment: What version of `seq` are you using? GNU `seq` on Linux doesn't do this for me.

Comment: Hm, interesting. I'm on a Mac. it seems to be using the BSD seq, but I can't tell which version it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the seq man page (`man seq`), you can control the output of the seq command using the `-f` flag, which accepts a C-style format string. The default format specifier is *%g* which explains why you are getting the exp print output for large numbers.

Ask seq to output a float without any decimal part:

```
seq -f'%.0f' 2180000 2180010
```

That should do what you want (tested on macOS and Ubuntu).

Alternatively, if you are using bash, you could also use the `{0..10}` style generator:

```
for i in {2180000..2180010}; do echo $i; done
```

Comment: great! thanks so much. will accept this as the answer as soon as stackoverflow lets me... you guys are too quick :)